# Angularjs, populate dropdown with certain value as selected

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Inside ng-repeat, i have a select dropdown which has to be filled with certain selected value if there is data in the obj.Name1 else it should select the default first value in the options.

```
<table ng-controller="TestCtrl">

 <tr ng-repeat="obj in MainArray" >
<td>{{$index + 1}}</td>
<td ng-model="MainArray">{{obj.FirstValue}}</td>
<td>

<!-- if obj.Name1 has some value then it has to be selected in select dropdown, else default first value of dropdown must be displayed  -->
<!-- dont know how to put a condition so as to display the obj.Name1 value in the dropdown-->

<select ng-model="DropdownArray[$index]" ng-options="test.ID as test.Name for test in DropdownList" >
     <option>Default Value</option>
 </select>

</table>
```

//Controller

```
.controller('TestCtrl',function($scope, $rootScope, $http, URL, $state, $modal, $interval, Notification){



   $scope.DropdownArray=[];

    $scope.DropdownList=[
{"ID":"1","Name":"one"},
{"ID":"2","Name":"two"},
{"ID":"3","Name":"three"}
];

    $scope.MainArray=[
{"FirstValue":"First","Name1":""} ,
{"FirstValue":"Second","Name1":"two"} ,
{"FirstValue":"Third","Name1":"one"},
{"FirstValue":"Forth","Name1":""}
];

})
```

My question is, if `obj.Name1` contains any value, how can I display it as selected option?

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: If obj.Name1 contains any value then i how can i display it as selected option

for example,  {"FirstValue":"Second","Name1":"two"} 

Name1 has the value two, that shud be displayed as selected option (in DropdownArray[$index] )

Answer (score 0):

You can make an option that matches an empty string, and since the variable inside `ng-model` doesn't contain anything it will be matched against the empty value, as follows

```
<select ng-model="DropdownArray[$index]" ng-options="test.ID as test.Name for test in DropdownList" >
     <option value="">Default Value</option>
</select>
```

Comment: How can i display the obj.Name1 values inside the select dropdown? (i need DropdownArray[] for some other purpose , basically fr getting individual dropdown values)